# Eloquent relationship with extra column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following database structure:

Table addresses:

```
id  
state -> state code
country -> country code
```

(The above table structure cannot be changed)

Table countries:

```
id
code (unique)
```

Table states:

```
id
country_id (id from countries table)
code (unique for country_id)
```

The question is - is it possible to define for `Address` model relationship for state?

If I use:

```
public function stateRel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\State', 'state','code');
}
```

it obviously won't work because if I have 2 states with the same code (belonging to other countries) it won't find correct one. It should use also `country` from `addresses` to compare with `country_id` in states but to make it more complicated `country` doesn't hold id but code from `countries` table.

Comment: Can you create a db view?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried constraints on the belongTo relation?

```
public function stateRel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\State', 'state','code')->where('country_id', $this->country);
}
```

Comment: There's no `country_id` in the table I suppose. Also, won't work for eager loading.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, the relation is done on the table states, there's the country id there. And yes, you can do eager loading I think, `$this->country` is referring to each models country

Comment: 1 It won't work for eager loading - that wasn't a question. 2 There is no `country_id` on the addresses table, so you can't refer to `country_id` on the states table. It would require either `country_id` or `country_code` on both tables, which is not the case here, unless the OP just didn't paste this pretty important detail...